# How can I see the most recent tagged commits in my repository?

Tags: git

I would like to do something like git log, but I would like to see only tagged commits.  I would like to see there tags, and when they were committed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`git-for-each-ref`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-for-each-ref.html), as in the following:

```
$ git for-each-ref --count=3 --sort='-*authordate' refs/tags |
  while read sha1 objtype refname; do
    echo "$refname - $sha1"
    GIT_PAGER=cat git log -1 $sha1
    echo
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

git tag -n will list the commit comments next to the tags, but no dates.